# Recover from creating wrong file system using 'mkfs.ext4' on external USB drive

Tags: linux, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning, filesystems

I ran the following command `$ sudo mkfs.ext4 /dev/sdb1` on a Transcend StoreJet 500GB external drive on Ubuntu 16.04 in an effort to try to use exFAT on Ubuntu. The was output was as follows:

```
mke2fs 1.42.13 (17-May-2015)
Creating filesystem with 122096000 4k blocks and 30531584 inodes
Filesystem UUID: 7595e30c-29a1-4149-9800-b5ba236359db
Superblock backups stored on blocks: 
    32768, 98304, 163840, 229376, 294912, 819200, 884736, 1605632, 2654208, 
    4096000, 7962624, 11239424, 20480000, 23887872, 71663616, 78675968, 
    102400000

Allocating group tables: done                            
Writing inode tables: done                            
Creating journal (32768 blocks): done
Writing superblocks and filesystem accounting information: done
```

This created a new file system on the drive, which is now also apparently unpartitioned, and all my data is lost. I've tried TestDisk using the `analyze` option which gave the error `Filesystem seems damaged` and also Photorec's search - without much success. I have never used them before, so I am not sure I am selecting the correct options.

What would you recommend I do to recover the data?

Comment: What is your question? You’ve stated multiple things, but haven’t indicated what you want to do now?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question. I would like to recover my data.

Comment: I have had the most success with Photorec. Try specifying the file types but it sounds like you have done that already :/

Answer (score 0):

If you ran photorec correctly and it did not find any data you are out of luck, and the best you can do is recreate a blank VFAT system.

That said, while it is possible there is no data for photorec to recover this seems a little unlikely. What command did you issue to start photorec, and are you certain you had the correct device?

I confess that I am wondering if /dev/sdb1 is the appropriately disk and if you ran photorec with the correct privileges and options.

That said, what you have done does mean that simple recovery of filenames, directory structure etc is very unlikely - you need to realise you have converted the disk from a FAT system to a Linux based EXT system, so data loss is inevitable. Sorry.